# Question about the notation $S \subset T$ ,where $S$ and $T$ are operators

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

I want to prove that if $S\subset T$. Then $T^{*}\subset S^{*}$.

But what does $S\subset T$ mean? $S$ and $T$ are operators and not sets.. :/

Comment: What is an *operator* ? it is a *linear map*. What is a *map* ? it is a *function*. What is a function* ? it is a * relation*. And what is a relation ? It is a *set*.

Comment: It's bad notation, but it probably means the graph of $S$ is included in the graph of $T$. A better, often-used notation for graph inclusion is $S\prec T$ meaning strict extension and $S \preceq T$ allowing for possibly equality.

Answer (score 2):

It is standard notation and means that $T$ is an extension of $S$, i.e. $D(S)\subset D(T)$ and $T|_{D(S)}=S$ where $D(S)$ denotes the domain of $S$ (even shorter: $\Gamma(S)\subset\Gamma(T)$ where $\Gamma(S)$ is the graph of $S$).